# Display nested JSON using Flatlist React Native not showing data

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am making one screen where I am getting data from a fetch API call. In the console its showing the message success and giving the data. Below is the JSON I am getting from API response

```
{
    "msg": "Success",
    "type": "success",
    "data": {
        "15": {
            "order_number": "",
            "products_info": [
                {
                    "name": "Rose",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "base_price": 75
                }
            ],
            "can_dispatch": false,
            "can_complete": false,
             },
         "16": {
            "order_number": "",
             "products_info": [
                {
                     "name": "Rosehip",
                      "qty": 1,
                      "base_price": 205
                }
            ],
            "can_dispatch": false,
            "can_complete": false,   
            },
            "17": {
                 "order_number": "",
                 "products_info": [
                {
                     "name": "Cloth Bag ",
                     "qty": 4,
                     "base_price": 20
                },
            ],
            "can_dispatch": false,
            "can_complete": false,   
            }
    },
"success": true
}
```

I want to display using FlatList. I am getting a response from API and storing in this.state.items
Here is my code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                    data={this.state.items.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => 
                    <View style={{height: 50}}>
                    <Text style={{height: 50}}>{item.products_info.name}</Text>
                    <View style={{height: 1,backgroundColor:'gray'}}></View>
                    </View>
                    }
                />
        </View>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As per Flatlist docs for React Native, the "data" prop must be an array.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-data

I've modified your code to get it working - https://snack.expo.io/YkdUl2G4B
Please take a look and let me know if you have any questions or concerns around it.